# Can a file be automatically uploaded to an http server?

Tags: ios, codeigniter, upload

From an iPhone app, I want to upload the result (pdf) to my http server (Code Igniter) automatically, i.e. without asking user to pick a file and press "upload".

I referenced to [this guide](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) on Code Igniter but found it not so helpful since it still asks user to choose a file (on iOS, the only resourse is Camera roll)

Is there a way to upload file automatically, seamlessly?

Thanks

Comment: At first sight, a way of doing that would be to send the file encoded to your server.Then you'll have to decode the file in PHP and save it.

Comment: If you are asking if HTML upload form can automatically upload file, without asking user - no it can not, as it would allow anyone to steal any file from client machine. That would be enormous security hole.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. That explains a lot for my question